# If development on the Stack Exchange iOS/Android apps has ceased indefinitely, what should we do to their bug reports and feature requests?

Tags: discussion, android-app, ios-app, development

It's been a while since the Stack Exchange team last had an iOS or Android developer, and the development job on the apps have not had any insights for years.

That, however, doesn't deny the fact that there are still many users to them. As a consequence, people are continuing to submit bug reports and sometimes feature requests about them.

If development on iOS/Android apps has ceased indefinitely, what should we do to their bug reports and feature requests?

Are we going to keep them with the hope that development on apps will resurrect one day, or just ignore them and telling users that development has frozen?

Comment: Related: [Photo upload on iOS app in gardening exchange fails most of the time](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/326797) (Comment: *Thanks for the report! Unfortunately we're not making fixes to the mobile apps at this time.* – [Adam Lear♦ May 23 at 15:54](/posts/comments/1072423))

Comment: What do you mean by *"the development job on the apps have not had any insights"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Honestly, even I myself have forgot what I was thinking when I first picked that word *insight*. Maybe I meant "updates" (new releases, announcements on changes, etc.)

Comment: Perhaps the extant [bug] reports and [feature-request]s can be closed as dupes pointing to the FAQ, ‘[How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075)’ …

Answer (score 21):

Just leave the questions alone. Most of the apps are still available for download and some people use them.

On the slim chance that development resumes, bug reports and feature requests will be useful. In the meantime, leaving these questions open allows users to post workarounds as answers.

Answer (score 13):

There's nothing that should be done with these questions because:

1) There are many links to them which would unexpectedly break for <10k-ers,

2) They are useful historical artifacts to know and understand the history of SE,

3) There's always the chance of development starting up again.

They should not be deleted for reasons 1 and 2, and they should not be closed as "can no longer be reproduced" for reason 3 and because they can still be reproduced by using the apps, even if they aren't going to be fixed.

The one thing we can and probably should do is specify in the tag wikis and/or excerpts that development has stopped and that bug reports and feature requests are not likely to be fixed/implemented to warn posters of new questions and viewers of old questions.

Other than that, bug reports and feature requests for the iOS/android apps are fine and should stay as-is.