# Photo upload on iOS app in gardening exchange fails most of the time

Tags: support, bug, status-declined, ios-app, uploader

App fails to upload the files most of the time, I've seen some incidents succeed also, but very rarely. Screenshot for details

> [image: Request failed error]

Comment: Thanks for the report! Unfortunately we're not making fixes to the mobile apps at this time.

Comment: @Megan hey, any chance to get official answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324550/if-development-on-the-stack-exchange-ios-android-apps-has-ceased-indefinitely-w)? Thanks.

Comment: @ShadowTheCurlyBracedWizard Well, since there's a bounty, sure. ;) Yes. We need to do a bit more discussion internally, but I'll make sure we follow up.

Comment: @MeganRisdal thanks, looking forward to hear updates. :)

Comment: @AdamLear is it still the case that mobile app development is stopped? As a heavy user of the iOS app, it’s frustrating to see that bugs such as this one persist and make the app unusable in some ways.

Comment: @ARich It is, yeah. We have no plans to resume native app development at the moment and both apps [have been delisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363043) from the app stores.