# Unable to upload image via Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, uploader

I'm unable to upload any image using the SE Android app.

> [image]

Screenshot with error is uploaded via web form.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LM-G710
- OS Version: 8.0.0 (190492326deb8.FGN)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Photo upload on iOS app in gardening exchange fails most of the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326797/photo-upload-on-ios-app-in-gardening-exchange-fails-most-of-the-time)

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard not a duplicate, since iOS app uploader is working for me as a charm.

Comment: You’re probably right, but the link might still be useful to the devs (partially joking). Retracted vote.

Comment: I have the same issue. Not sure if the bug was supposed to be corrected in the meantime...