# Is there a direct way to access questions in the Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: feature-request, support, android-app

Is there a direct/fast way to access a certain [tag] on a certain (site) from the Stack Exchange Android app?

I currently do:

1. Open the app
2. Open side window
3. Choose site (for example, Stack Overflow)
4. Tap on search
5. Write `[` `t` `a` `g` `]`
6. Search and sometimes filter by new

This is too cumbersome. There must be an easier shortcut, at least for favorite tags...

Comment: Wait, we have an app?

Comment: Which app? There's a tags tab on the iOS app.

Comment: The android app!

Comment: @Abdullah Note that development for the Android app is [currently frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app).

Comment: @Blue I didn't know that. This is quite unfortunate though! Do you know why? I find the app very helpful to catch up!

Comment: @Abdullah Can't say for sure, but I guess they haven't had any Android developer in a while cf. [If development on the Stack Exchange iOS/Android apps has ceased indefinitely, what should we to do their bug reports and feature requests?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324550/if-development-on-the-stack-exchange-ios-android-apps-has-ceased-indefinitely-w). Anyway, I find the app far inferior to the mobile site. If you use Chrome (on Android), you can save links to individual pages [on your homescreen](https://www.wikihow.com/Set-a-Bookmark-Shortcut-in-Your-Home-Screen-on-Android).

Comment: @Blue Could be, the main answer to the linked question makes a lot of sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: On the iOS app there is a direct way.

Comment: @Alex too bad we don't have this on the android version!