# Add saved searches

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app

The ability to save custom searches and load them at will in the mobile app would be really nice. I frequently search for specific tags when I log on to answer new questions (e.g. `[java] -[android]` on StackOverflow).

Maybe add a "default search" setting as well; I usually use the same search filters every time I go to answer questions on SO, as I am not yet extensively proficient in multiple languages.

Comment: Looks like the ios-app already has that feature: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243538/158100 ?

Comment: also worth knowing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324550/if-development-on-the-stack-exchange-ios-android-apps-has-ceased-indefinitely-w